# Html.HiddenFor formats DateTime incorrectly in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, formatting

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC3 application in C# and have found that calling `Html.HiddenFor` in my view will render a `DateTime` differently (and incorrectly) to if i was to call `Html.DisplayFor`.

The model its taking the value from does have a DisplayFormat decorator and this seems to work for `Html.DisplayFor`. The property in question is written as:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime MeetingStartDate { get; set; }
```

And the view displays this using:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MeetingStartDate)
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MeetingStartDate)
```

The DisplayFor call will render the date as `16/04/2012` however the HiddenFor will render it as  `value="04/16/2012 00:00:00"`.

I've tried changing the current culture to set a `DateTimeFormat` but this had no effect.

The current culture is en-GB so it shouldn't be printing en-US dates anyway.

Comment: If the value is hidden, why does it matter how it's formatted? Presumably it only needs to be parsed again on the way back... if it's not for *human* consumption, the format shouldn't matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet For some reason this invalidates the model, im working in en-GB but its printing out a en-US date. But *only* for this hidden element

Comment: You could use a custom editor template See the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305262/asp-net-mvc-format-of-hidden-datetime

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An in-view alternative using TextBoxFor will work if you specify the date format and the html hidden attribute.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreatedDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}", htmlAttributes: new { @type = "hidden" })
```

Comment: The datetime was not passing until I changed the format to a US formatted date like {0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}

Comment: a more generic format will be "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}" but otherwise work perfectly

Answer (score 8):

If you want to generate a hidden field that respects the format you defined you could define a custom editor template to override the default one (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/HiddenInput.cshtml`):

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelMetadata.HideSurroundingHtml) 
{
    @ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue
}
@Html.Hidden("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue)
```

and now you decorate your model property with the `[HiddenInput]` attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public DateTime MeetingStartDate { get; set; }
```

and in your view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MeetingStartDate)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingStartDate)
```

which will use the correct format for the hidden value:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The MeetingStartDate field is required." id="MeetingStartDate" name="MeetingStartDate" type="hidden" value="15/03/2012" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can outsmart the HiddenFor implementation and reuse the TextBoxFor instead and manually set *type="hidden"*.

Something like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString HiddenInputFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
  IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributesTmp = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
  if (htmlAttributesTmp.ContainsKey("type"))
  {
    htmlAttributesTmp["type"] = "hidden";
  }
  else
  {
    htmlAttributesTmp.Add("type", "hidden");
  }

  return html.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributesTmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model, for the Get function of the MeetingStartDate property can you return a formatted DateTime?

The DisplayFormat is not going to work for hidden values because MVC is creating a value in the hidden field that can be parsed correctly during the Form Submit action from the data that is currently set for the property.

What you have is expected actions by MVC.

Comment: How would you return a formatted date, I thought the formatting was only applied when you converted the `DateTime` to a string?

Comment: I understand that you would like to use attributes to scaffold your items, but in this situation you would have to use `@Html.Hidden("MeetingStartDate", model.MeetingStartDate.ToShortDateString())`

Comment: Event if I use ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") it will still output the date as an en-US date

Comment: did you try to add your culture to that statement? `ToString("d", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));`

Comment: No, but using `Model.MeetingStartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyy")` did make it output the date in the correct format. My understanding was that using `Model` would force use of the models value, otherwise the post variables where used?

Comment: I added `<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />` to my web.config and your first comment solved the problem but using `ToString(format)`. Ta

Answer (score -2):

if you give id like that the problem does not occur

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.DiscountRate,new {  @id = "DiscountRate", @Value=Model.DiscountRate})%>
```