# Milliseconds are being truncated by an ASP.NET MVC Hidden Input element

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a View that renders a list of items, and each item contains a `Date` property.

```
<%:Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Items[j].Date)%>
```

A number of other properties are hidden or shown, and the user is able to enter comments against any item and save these comments to the database. It's a 'bulk edit' type View.

I've used these Views before to good effect, but I'm having a problem with the Date property because it renders thus

```
<input name="Items[3].Date" type="hidden" value="3/05/2012 11:56:48 AM" />
```

The problem is that I need to use the DateTime as a part of the primary key for this data item. I could truncate the milliseconds in the database to allow the match but there is no guarantee that there will only be one data point per second.

How do I ensure that the hidden input field for my `DateTime` retains all of the property's information, including the milliseconds component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well do you really need to use

```
<%:Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Items[j].Date)%>
```

why not just keep it simple

```
<input type="hidden" name="Items[<%:j%>].Date" value="<%:model.Items[j].Date.ToString("dd/MM/yy/ HH:mm:ss.fffff")%>"/>
```

Comment: Clearly your definition of simple is different from mine. That's a lot more to remember then the original. Because now every view containing a hidden date needs to be updated to a much larger line of text.

Comment: I try not to depend on hidden stuff a lot, They come with their own history. Which you will have to learn wen you to learn them the lease

Answer (score 1):

I've not had any success forcing the format of a DateTime in a `HiddenFor` field.

The `DisplayFormat` attribute can force the format for a `DisplayFor` field but has no effect on a `HiddenFor` field.

I resorted to the below no-quite-a-hack to get this to work - serialize and deserialize the ticks property to ensure the true time is retained.

```
public long DateTicks 
{ 
    get
    {
        return this.Date.HasValue ? this.Date.Value.Ticks : 0; 
    } 
    set 
    { 
        if (value == 0) 
            this.Date = null; 
        else 
            this.Date = new DateTime(value); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<%:Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Items[j].Date.Ticks)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **DisplayFormat** attribute on the Date property in your model, and spell out the milliseconds in the format string:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyyMMddhhmmssfff}")]
```

Comment: Heh, was just going to point that out - beat me to it. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724713/html-hiddenfor-formats-datetime-incorrectly-in-asp-net

Comment: This doesn't work for me. According to the linked question this attribute applies to Display fields but not Hidden fields.